# How to set ZoomControls on the ActionBar for Imageview in Android?

Tags: android

How can I zoom a Imageview using ZoomControls? I want to place the ZoomControls on the ActionBar.

Comment: Check how pinch zoom works. In the action bar you can create your own logic and do the same.

Comment: @TerrilThomas Can I able get the Motionevent with in setOnLongClickListener?

Comment: you can use OnTouchEvent to get Motionevent.

http://www.androidsnippets.com/handle-touch-events-ontouchevent
http://codetheory.in/android-ontouchevent-ontouchlistener-motionevent-to-detect-common-gestures/

Comment: @TerrilThomas because my project is Add pin mark image(Imageview) on the Relative layout("Bitmap Image" not google map).I successfully created the dynamic pin mark image and fit on the Relative Layout(Bitmap image).I want just zoom the Relative layout and fit the pin So I asked this.Please reply me bro.

Comment: I guess rather than zooming the layout you can simply use imageView and I would surely recommend you to check the pinch zoom in android. It works on the same background

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ZoomControls` as an Action View

**Example:**

On menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:id="@+id/action_zoom"
        android:title="@string/action_zoom"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:actionViewClass="android.widget.ZoomControls" />
</menu>
```